# Turn off textarea resizing

Tags: html, textarea

I'm trying to turn off textarea resizing in my site; right now I'm using this method:

```
.textarea {
    clear:left;
    min-width: 267px;
    max-width: 267px;
    min-height:150px;
    max-height:150px;
}
```

I know that my method is not correct and I'm searching for a better one in JavaScript. I'm a beginner, so the best solution for me will be HTML5 or jQuery.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

**Try this CSS to disable resizing**

The CSS to disable resizing for all textareas looks like this:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

You could instead just assign it to a single textarea by name (where the textarea HTML is ):

```
textarea[name=foo] {
    resize: none;
}
```

Or by id (where the textarea HTML is ):

```
#foo {
    resize: none;
}
```

Taken from:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/

Comment: Instead of just linking to a solution, you should explain it a little here. A lot of other people looking at this question in the future won't be bothered to click a link for an answer. Add some detail here and I'll +1 your answer.

Answer (score 23):

this will do your job

```
  textarea{
        resize:none;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

CSS3 can solve this problem. Unfortunately it's only supported on [60% of used browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=resize) nowadays.

For IE and iOS you can't turn off resizing but you can limit the `textarea` dimension by setting its `width` and `height`.

```
/* One can also turn on/off specific axis. Defaults to both on. */
textarea { resize:vertical; } /* none|horizontal|vertical|both */
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/doxk6Lnq/)

Answer (score 6):

This is works for me

```html
<textarea
  type='text'
  style="resize: none"
>
Some text
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just one extra option, if you want to revert the default behaviour for all textareas in the application, you could add the following to your CSS:

```
textarea:not([resize="true"]) {
  resize: none !important;
}
```

And do the following to enable where you want resizing:

```
<textarea resize="true"></textarea>
```

Have in mind this solution might not work in all browsers you may want to support. You can check the list of support for `resize` here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize

Answer (score 1):

As per the question, i have listed the answers in **javascript**

**By Selecting TagName**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].style.resize = "none";
```

**By Selecting Id**

```
document.getElementById('textArea').style.resize = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//CSS:
.textarea {
    resize: none;
    min-width: //-> Integer number of pixels
    min-height: //-> Integer number of pixels
    max-width: //-> min-width
    max-height: //-> min-height
}
```

above code works on most browsers

```
//HTML:
<textarea id='textarea' draggable='false'></textarea>
```

do both for it to work on the maximum number of browsers

Answer (score -1):

It can done easy by just using html draggable attribute

```
<textarea name="mytextarea" draggable="false"></textarea>
```

Default value is true.

Comment: The question is about resizing the textarea, not drag and drop.
So as expected, setting this attribute on a textarea doesn't do the trick in Chrome (at least).