# Prevent resizing and scrolling of <textarea>

Tags: javascript, resize, textarea

I would like to add a `<textarea>` on my web page. Which can contain a maximum of 21 lines. I would like to prevent the re-sizing of the text area when more elements are coming to the page. I partially gain it by giving the `maxlength` property. But the count using line number is not effective. Because if someone give 1 new line and type some data then the line order will give a true value but the max length give wrong value.

**suppose if my textarea has `maxlength=100` and one line can contain upto 10 letters. And I limit the row number as 10. If I give 10 blank `enter` key press, then it will stop at line 10. And if I give 100 characters, then also it will work correctly. But if I type 1 character on !st line, Then Press `Enter` and one character on second line then press `Enter`. Then the text area will allow 98 more characters, which will resize the `textarea`**

Is there any way to prevent re-sizing using the width of textarea? Please help

Comment: This answer shows how to limit lines with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501310/2038464 This answer shows how to prevent textarea resizing in chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11401654/2038464

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you for the suggestion. I already tried this. But it wont satisfy the conditions which I given in question.. :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your issue. Can you include the HTML and/ or JavaScript code you are using for this textarea? Also, what browser are you testing on?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/Hm6Q8/) is helpfull. But it wont go to new line when one line is complete :(

Answer (score 0):

Prevent resizing using CSS resize property:

```
.txt {
   resize: none;
}
```

Prevent users from adding too many values into a textarea:

```
<textarea maxlength="100" accesskey="10" row="10"></textarea>
```

Final code:

```
<textarea maxlength="100" class="txt" accesskey="10" row="10" style="resize:none">
   My text is
</textarea>
```

Comment: This doesn't fully account for the 10 values per line argument in Chrome, IE, and Safari, but tested and works in Firefox and Opera (for whatever reason it worked in Opera but not Chrome when I tried it.)